# How can I call query in variable while declaring it in Hive?

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, hiveql

How can I call query in variable while declaring it in Hive? I am creating a shell script to drop partitions for previous date, so in the file.hql I am using :

```
Alter table table_name drop partition column >= ‘datesub(current_date-1)’;
```

But it is not working, so I have tried to declare the condition in variable and then call here. So I first try to declare the variable then call it in query :

```
set var1= Select date_sub(current_date, 1)

Alter table table_name drop partition column >= ‘${hoveconf:var1}’;
```

But this is not working because the variable is not declared correctly. So how to declare the query under variable?

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not calculate variables before substitution, variables are being substituted as is. Also functions and sub-queries are not allowed in partition specification.

The solution is to calculate variable in a shell and pass it to the script:

```
bash$ dt=$(date -d '-1 day' +%Y-%m-%d)
bash$ hive -e "ALTER TABLE table_name drop partition (column >='$dt')"
```

Or if you prefer to call script file, then pass hiveconf variable:

```
  bash$ dt=$(date -d '-1 day' +%Y-%m-%d)
  bash$ hive -hiveconf dt="$dt" -f script_name
```

#In the script use `'${hiveconf:dt}'`:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name drop partition (column >='${hiveconf:dt}')
```